# Google Chrome Portable Lag when scrolling or typing in dual GPU and selected power saving mode (use integrated GPU) in display setting

Tags: google-chrome, gpu

I have i7-13700k and GTX 1080 Ti build and want to use iGPU for chrome decode and 1080 Ti for gaming. using Chrome Portable 64bit from portableapps https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google-chrome-portable-64
I enable iGPU in BIOS and able to see two GPU in device manager and also selected power saving mode for chrome portable in display setting.
But when I use Chrome portable for website browsing it will be lag when scrolling or typing.
change it back to high performance, then lag will disappear.
Also i tried to use normal chrome and found no issue.
is there some issue about Chrome Portable in dual GPU setup?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It lagging because it has to render on the iGPU and copy over to the dedicated GPU. It should be better, but apparently isn't.